# URISyntaxException: Illegal character

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge

So, everytime i open project with VSC, java builds project, then screams 2 exact same problem being:

```
Could not fetch model of type 'BuildEnvironment' using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip'.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: z:\Projects\minecraft_mods\starting_mod-1.12.2\.
Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: z:\Projects\minecraft_mods\starting_mod-1.12.2\.
```

Theres exactly two of them, no matter how many times i restart VSC, it is always going to be 2 of them:
[image]

This has been happening for past two days, and i couldn't figure out anything, i tried editing gradlew.bat:

```
set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
```

into

```
set DIRNAME=.
```

I restarted VSC, same error.
Any suggestions ? This thing has been haunting me.

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual code but just by looking at error I'd try to change the path `z:\Projects\minecraft_mods\starting_mod-1.12.2\.` to one of: `z:\\Projects\\minecraft_mods\\starting_mod-1.12.2\\.` or `z:/Projects/minecraft_mods/starting_mod-1.12.2/.`

Comment: Yeah, but VSC does not show where that error is, i was trying to do that whole time, but i couldn't even find where that is used (using VSC's search feature). @makozaki